# How to execute more than one perl script in parallel on a linux machine?

Tags: linux, perl

I want run all script from the directory .
Like ,

The directory contains 40 script,i would like to run first 5 script parallel.after completing these scripts the next 5 script will be execute as well as the remaining.

Please give any solutions by using linux and perl commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the folder with the scripts run this bash script/command:

```
for var in $(ls *.pl)
do
    $var &
    # 5 simultaneous jobs 
    while test "$(jobs |wc -l)" -gt 4 
    do
        sleep 1
    done
done
```

this relies on you not having other background jobs running, test this by writing "jobs" on the commandline.

Comment: I have later learned that you can just use xargs to run multiple parallel jobs. To gzip files simultaneously with 4 processes:    
`ls *.pl |xargs -n1 -P4 gzip`

Answer (score 10):

Everyone loves to reinvent parallel execution tools.

- [parallel](http://enwp.org/GNU_parallel)
- [pexec](http://enwp.org/pexec)
- [runN](http://aaroncrane.co.uk/2008/07/runN/)
- [xapply](http://carrera.databits.net/~ksb/msrc/local/bin/xapply/xapply.html)

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) for the first 5 scripts? Have the 5th script write to some file that it has completed and continue onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget GNU Make!  Use a makefile like this and run with the -j option.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel

```
scripts=$(wildcard *.sh)
all: $(patsubst %.sh,%.out,$(scripts))
%.out: %.sh
    sh $< > $@ 2>&1
```

If you were working in Perl I'd suggest [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.9/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm)

Oh, and it seems that xargs on Linux has a -P option to run jobs in parallel.  I haven't used it as my GNU Make trick predates it.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write sth like below. It's pseudo code.

#!/bin/ksh

dir=$1
count=0
for script in $1/*
  do
   count++
   $i &
   add the pid to pidList array
   if( count==5){
     while(waitforProcessComplete(pidList){
     }
   }

  done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer GNU parallel. It's easy and fun - and the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) comes with many neat examples.

The big advantage: You don't have to write any code or Makefile to do run your scripts. Example:

```
# create the example scripts:
mkdir scripts
for i in {1..50}; do {echo '#!/bin/sh'; echo "echo $i"; echo "sleep 1" } > scripts/s$i.sh; done

# use parallel to run all these scripts, 5 at a time:
parallel -j 5 ::: scripts/*.sh
```